# Prestashop Cart Rules (By Fixed Price)

Tags: prestashop

I am using Prestashop 1.6 and my client has recently requested this promotion to be configured.

It looks like Cart Rules / Catalog Rules are the way, but I can't seem to get it.

Here's the scenario:
There are 3 items in CategoryA ($3 each), and 4 items in CategoryB ($4 each). Promotion is "Buy Any 4 @ $10".  So as long as there are 4 items in total in the cart (regardless of how many qty each from whichever product from whichever category), the price should be $10.

It definitely can't be done via discount amount or discount percentage, as we will not know the total amount of the cart.

Can this be done in the out of the box PS?  Or is there any premium module available?

P.S.: I have searched rather long in stackoverflow but seems weird that no one requires this feature? Or did I overlook it in PS?

Comment: You may need to write your own code/function that monitors your cart for items in catA and catB and if there are qualifying quantities then update the total. Don't forget that you'll need to work out if someone has added not quite enough for more than one whole multiple of your deal to not count it. I.e. "buy any four" (which they do) but they then add 3 extra (that don't meet your deal criteria).

Comment: @BigChris you're right.  It looks that way.  For now, I have raised an improvement request to PrestaShop to add a 4th option in Cart Rules discount selection, "Fixed Price".